# How to specify an ad-set-id in Facebook graph API URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using the [delivery endpoints](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/targeting#delivery) of the Facebook Marketing API (v3.2)

I've successfully got this one working:

```
/{AD_ACCOUNT}/delivery_estimate
```

(Note, as usual the docs are misleading and you have to use the prefix `act_` for it to work)

I *can't* get this to work:

```
/{AD_SET}/delivery_estimate
```

([Ad sets](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign) are groups of ads within a campaign).

If you just supply the number on its own, it fails, as you'd expect, with:

> Cannot determine the target object for this request. Currently
>   supported objects include ad account, business account and associated
>   object.

I've tried a few variations - ad_, adset_, ad-set_, ad_set, adsetid_ etc. - none of which work.

Anybody know what it is? I've not found anything in the API docs, so if anyone *does* have a Facebook URL that explains it…

Comment: How you calculate the delivery estimates value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer - there's **no** prefix or special way to write ad set IDs.  I'm unclear why it wasn't working before.

You can use this to get a list of adsets for the account (as an array in 'data'):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/act_0000000000/adsets
```

Then you just supply the ID on it's own after the API version number:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/12345678901234567/delivery_estimate?targeting_spec...
```